# self.model() in django custom UserManager

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-authentication, django-users

So, I'm fairly new to Django. Notwithstanding the fact that my code works after following the Django docs 'Customizing authentication in Django', I don't get how the self.model(...) in their example actually works, where it comes from and how it functions with 'self'.

This is the example found at the bottom of the docs.

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, date_of_birth, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

   ->   user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
...
```

Comment: Something that uses models, calls the `add_to_class` **class** method of `ModelBase` (which all models have as a meta-class) which calls `contribute_to_class` of  `BaseManager` (which all managers inherit from) which sets the `model` field.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, what you define here is a `MyUserManager` class. This inherits from the [**`BaseUserManager`** class <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L16). This is a subclass of the [**`Manager`** class <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/manager.py#L165). You actually use manager all the time. For example `SomeModel.objects` is a manager.

A manager has, if it is used, a reference to the *model* it manages. So `SomeModel.objects` is a manager, but that manager has an attribute `.model` that actually refers back to the `SomeModel` class.

Now a class in Python is typically *callable*. If you for example call `int('42')`, you call the `int(..)` *constructor*. In this case your `self.model` will - by default - by the `User` model (although that can be overwritten).

Now in Django the constructor of a model takes, named parameters, to construct a model instance. If you write `User(date_of_birth=date(2018, 7, 3), email='bob@work.com')`, then you construct an *unsaved* `User` instance with as field values July 3rd 2018 as `date_of_birth`, and `'bob@work.com'` as `email`.

So here you typically construct a `User` instance (or an instance of another model you used to represent `User`s). You then later use `user.save()` to save that instance to the database, and return it.